# Shopware 5.2.11 include JavaScript in my plugin

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

I want to add a JavaScript file in my plugin.  I was following this [tutorial](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-quick-start/) and was able to successfully get the Slogan of the Day on my installation (vagrant).

Additionally I want to load a JavaScript file. I changed the of index.tpl and added the following lines:

```
   {* Include own Javascript Code *}
    {block name="frontend_index_header_javascript_jquery_lib"}
      {debug}
      {$smarty.block.parent}
      {if $myVariable}<script type="text/javascript" src="{link   file='frontend/_public/src/js/myFile.js'}"></script>{/if}
    {/block}
```

Taking a look at the source code of the generated html the script tag is successfully loaded. However, my JavaScript file won't be loaded at all. Where do I have to put the file in my plugin folder ?

Currently I have this structure

```
NameOfZipfile.zip
└──Frontend
   ├─MyPlugin
   │ └─Views
   │   ├─_public
   │   │ └─src
   │   │   └─js
   │   │     └─myFile.js
   │   └─frontend
   │     └─index
   │       └─index.tpl
   └─Bootstrap.php
```

I am using shopware 5.2.11. I don't want to add inline-script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey guys. I managed to solve the probleb by myself. I will mark the title as solved!

Solution: See edit in Question above

Comment: Don't put answers in questions. Don't put "solved" in question titles. Write an actual answer and accept it.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help. I was busy but now I am back. I will do this in the future. I am sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solution, I added following to the Bootstrap.php install method:

```
$this->subscribeEvent('Theme_Compiler_Collect_Plugin_Javascript', 'addJsFiles');
```

And this function:

```
 public function addJsFiles(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args){
    $jsFiles = array(__DIR__ . '/Views/_public/src/js/myFile.js');

    return new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($jsFiles);
}
```

Comment: If you use Grunt dont forget to add your js files to /web/cache/config_' + shopId + '.json'

Answer (score 0):

If using grunt you'll use this command to add all plugin's js files to your  /web/cache/config_' + shopId + '.json' files:
bin/console sw:theme:dump:configuration